# Haskell package installed but not found (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-install

I installed `ghc` and `cabal-install` on Ubuntu using [this way](https://www.haskell.org/downloads/linux).
When I install a package using `cabal sandbox init` and `cabal install thepackage`, the installation runs fine, but the package is not found in GHC (message: "It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package."). 
I have spent a couple of hours in trying to solve this problem, unsuccessfully. I took a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631925/haskell-package-installed-but-not-found), but it is for Windows, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212833/haskell-cabal-i-just-installed-packages-but-now-the-packages-are-not-found), but it doesn't help me, [this FAQ](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal-Install#I_just_installed_packages.2C_but_now_the_packages_are_not_found), but I tried with and without the `--global` option, and the result is the same. 
Some info about my installation:

```
$ which cabal
/opt/cabal/1.22/bin/cabal
$ which ghc
/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin/ghc
```

I have a `~/.ghc` folder, but it is empty. It looks like the installed packages are in the folder `~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org` and `~/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3`.

Comment: If you're within the sandbox then the installed packages should be in something like `./.cabal-sandox`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631925/haskell-package-installed-but-not-found?noredirect=1&lq=1) is __not__ windows specific. You have to use `cabal exec ghc` to use things in the sandbox.

Comment: @Zeta You're right, it works with `cabal exec ghci` ! Thank you !

Comment: @Zeta but it doesn't work if I run `cabal exec ghci` from a folder different than `~/` ....

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: You can only use the packages in the sandbox where you've installed them, e.g. `cd path/to/wd; cabal install package1 package2; cabal exec ghci`. You need to either symlink the cabal-sandbox, or use a command line option for that. If that's too much of a hassle, use [`stack`](http://haskellstack.org).

Comment: @Zeta That's annoying... And how to run `ghc` with options ? `cabal exec ghc -O ...` : "unrecognized 'exec' option `-O'".

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: That's another question ("How can I use GHC with a cabal sandbox not installed in the current directory?"), and the answer would be [`-package-db`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-databases). You're aware that there is documentation out there, right? :D

Comment: @Zeta That's the second day I spend my time with this problem and I've lost my patience with all these documentations which look like Chinese for me... ;-) I'll continue another day. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, you're welcome, and [here is your explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38507261/1139697).