# How can I use GHC with a cabal sandbox that's not in the current working directory?

Tags: haskell, cabal-sandbox

If I create a cabal sandbox with `cabal sandbox init`, I can use `cabal repl` or `cabal exec ghc(i)` to work with those packages without creating a project:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/example && cd /tmp/example
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cabal install QuickCheck
$ cabal exec ghci
Prelude> :m Test.QuickCheck
Prelude Test.QuickCheck>
```

However, if I change the path to something else, even to a subdirectory, I cannot access the packages anymore:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/example/sub && cd /tmp/example/sub
$ cabal exec ghci
Prelude> :m Test.QuickCheck
<no location info>:
    Could not find module ‘Test.QuickCheck’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

Is there any way to use the contents from the sandbox, without copying its content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `cabal` will only respect sandboxes in the current working directory. However, there are several options where you can specify a sandbox location for cabal or the package databse for GHC.

## Using cabal features

You can use `cabal`'s `--sandbox-config-file` option to specify a sandbox configuration, e.g.

```
$ cabal --sandbox-config-file=/tmp/example/cabal.sandbox.config exec ghci
Prelude> :m Test.QuickCheck
Prelude Test.QuickCheck>
```

This also enables you to change the sandbox from other places, which comes in handy if you just want to install random stuff into a temporary place:

```
$ cabal --sandbox-config-file=/tmp/example/cabal.sandbox.config install lens
$ cabal --sandbox-config-file=/tmp/example/cabal.sandbox.config repl
Prelude> :m Control.Lens
Prelude Control.Lens> :m Test.QuickCheck
Prelude Control.Lens Test.QuickCheck>
```

Since this gets cumbersome after a while, you should probably add an alias

```
$ alias sandboxed-cabal="cabal --sandbox-config-file=/tmp/example/cabal.sandbox.config"
$ sandboxed-cabal repl
Prelude>
```

## Using `ghc -package-db`

Alternatively, you can directly specify the package database when you use GHC with [`-package-db`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-databases):

```
$ ghci -package-db /tmp/example/.cabal-sandbox/<ARCH>-packages.conf.d
Prelude> :m Test.QuickCheck
Prelude Test.QuickCheck>
```

The `<ARCH>` depends on your system and the used GHC, e.g. on a 64bit Linux and GHC 7.10.3 it's `x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3-packages.conf.d`. You can then use all packages in that database:

```
$ ghci -package-db /tmp/example/.cabal-sandbox/<ARCH>-packages.conf.d
Prelude> :m Control.Lens
Prelude Control.Lens>
```

Again, an alias should come in handy.

## Using `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH`

Last, but not least, you can adjust an environment variable. However, if the environment variable [`GHC_PACKAGE_PATH`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#the-ghc-package-path-environment-variable) exists, it will overwrite GHC's usual package databases, so you either need to check `ghc-pkg list` and add them too

```
$ GHC_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ghc/7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/package.conf.d/:/tmp/example/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3-packages.conf.d ghci
```

or use [`-global-package-db`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#ghc-flag--global-package-db) and [`-user-package-db`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#ghc-flag--user-package-db) to reenable them:

```
$ GHC_PACKAGE_PATH=/tmp/example/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3-packages.conf.d ghci -global-package-db -user-package-db
```

Comment: Zeta you are my savior :) You could accept your own answer... Oh I see, in fact you wrote it today. Really cool.